# Interval classification in r

Tags: r, classification, intervals

I have two dataframes as follows

```
str(daily)  
Classes ‘grouped_df’,‘tbl_df’,‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':15264 obs.of 3 variables:
$ steps   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ date    : Date, format: "2012-10-02" "2012-10-02" "2012-10-02" ...
$ interval: int  0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...

interval<-data.frame(unique(daily$interval))

 str(interval)
'data.frame':   288 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ unique.daily.interval.:int 0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 100..2350 2355
```

using dplyr, what I intended to do was find the mean of daily$steps for each interval across daily$Date using the following

```
mutate(daily,class=cut(daily$steps,c(0,interval$unique.daily.interval.),
       include.lowest = TRUE) %>%
group_by(class) %>%
summarise(Mean = mean(daily$steps)))
```

The code fails giving the following error

```
Error: 'breaks' are not unique
```

which I have isolated to the 'class=cut' function. I have checked the interval df for uniqueness being only 288 values. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong ?  Here is a reference I used [Create class intervals in r and sum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653577/create-class-intervals-in-r-and-sum-values)

Here is a link to the data in question [Activity monitoring data](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip)

thanks.

Comment: Could you check the value of interval$unique.daily.interval. and let us know what it is?  BTW,   does the variable name really end in a period?

Comment: I read your question and had a look of your data. I could be wrong. But, seeing your code, I wonder if you were trying to create a group variable with  `interval`. Were you trying to create 288 groups? Or were you trying to create a certain number of groups using `cut()`?  It seems that you would want something like this although I am not sure what you would want to do with Date: `daily %>% group_by(interval = as.character(interval)) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(steps, na.rm = TRUE))`.

Comment: interval$unique.daily.interval.
    [1]    0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55  100  105  110    115  120  125  130...
     ...[267] 2210 2215 2220 2225 2230 2235 2240 2245 2250 2255 2300     2305 2310 2315 2320 2325 2330 2335 2340
    [286] 2345 2350 2355

of class 'integer'

Comment: yes the variable name does end in a period, which is what the machine gave me. bad syntax , I know :(

Comment: @David You can avoid such a column name by writing something like this: `interval <- data.frame(foo = unique(daily$interval))`.

Comment: @jazz good one ! Yes the group variable is a time interval in 5 min blocks across any 24h period. So 24*60/5 =288 intervals(groups). Your code worked a treat and much simpler than what I tried. 

The **summarise** function appears to have taken care of the Date as it has taken the mean for each of time intervals over a two month period. BTW,  I'm wondering why you changed the interval value from int to char ?

Comment: @David You do not need to use as.character. I gotta get ready for work now, so I cannot really help you more. But seeing what you said, don't you need the date object in a different format (e.g., 2016-12-07 08:00:00) instead of 2016-12-07? One more. Do you want to have mean for interval level for each month? If so, you need to create a group variable indicating month. If I have a bit of time later, I'll try to help you out.

Comment: @David I just read your comment again now. Do you need to get mean for each interval for October and November separately? If not, was the previous code enough for you? Let me know.